# Shoutcast stream Error(0,0) in Android 2.2 but it works in Android 2.3 and above

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to play a radio stream on my Android application. I'm using MediaPlayer. So as simple as instantiate, setDataSource, prepareAsync and play is my code below (running on the mainActivity). The method startPlaying is called when I press a play button in my UI:

```
public void onPlayOrStop(View v) {
        if (v == btnPlay) {
            startPlaying();
        } else if (v == btnStop) {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

private void startPlaying() {
        btnStop.setEnabled(true);
        btnStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
        btnPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        pbProgramaPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (player == null) {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
        }
        else {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.stop();
            }
            player.reset();
        }

        try {
            player.setDataSource("http://67.213.213.143:8048"); // a nice Hard Rock radio from shoutcast
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                pbProgramaPlay.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            }
        });
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pbProgramaPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnStop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
                pbProgramaPlay.setProgress(0);
                pbProgramaPlay.setSecondaryProgress(0);
            }
        });
        player.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                player.start();

                vlDuracaoProgramaPlay = player.getDuration();

                atualizaProgressBarPlay();
            }
        });

        player.prepareAsync();


    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (player != null) {
            if(player.isPlaying()) {
                player.stop();
            }
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }

        btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
        btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnStop.setEnabled(false);
        btnStop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pbProgramaPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

When running on Android 2.3 device, it works well. After few seconds the stream starts and I can hear the radio.
When running on Android 2.2 device it goes until I call player.prepareAsync(). I keep expecting a call to my `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() listener`. But it is never called. Instead, my `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() liestener` is fired.

Using debug, I see the parameters "what" and "extra" equal to 0 from the

`public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)` method.

Looking at the LogCat from my Eclipse IDE it shows Error(0,0)

Has anybody faced this error? I did not find this error in StackOverflow. Only happens when I'm running against my old Android 2.2 device.

My minSdkVersion is 8
My targetSdkVersion is 19

As I've read in Android's documentation I believe this code had to work in 2.2 as in 2.3. Am I right? Why isn't it?

Comment: I'd compare the implementation of media player between the platforms... however, with less and 1% active 2.2 devices... is it really worth your time?

Comment: @323go My device is 2.2 and I would like to support that version and above. I thought the implementation would be the same for 2.2 and above as it is wrote in the documentation. It's important to me because I would like to have my application reaching some "fogotten" devices and their users.